# Django Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

After searching, I have yet to find the solution to my jquery-related question online.

I have multiple `(div class='rate')` elements on a page that I would like to be updatable via ajax. index.html:

```
    {% for thing in thing_list %}
    <div class='rate'><a href='{% url thing_rating %}'>Rate</a></div>
    {% endfor %}
```

They reference a url kind of like: urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/rate/(?P<score>[\d\-]+)/$', 'myview', name='thing_rating'),
```

I do check for `request.is_ajax()` in the view: view.py:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        // doing some other stuff here
        return render_to_response('rate.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My ajax needs help..:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
$('div#rate').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"/????/",
  data: { ????? },
  success: function(data){ ????? },
  error: function(){ alert("Error"); },
});
}
```

How do I reference the url in the above jquery? Via the same regex as in my urls.py?

What should I be passing as the data and success functions? All of the heavy lifting is done in my view..

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning a rendered template. So, I would suggest using html dataType in your ajax() function and append it inside a div where you want to display it. Let me know if you have any other questions.

```
function vote(){
    $('div#vote').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var href = $(this).attr('href'); //Referring the anchor object which is clicked
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:href,
      dataType: html,
      success: function(data, status, xhr){ $('#div_to_load_html').html(data); },
      error: function(){ alert("Error"); },
    });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But I also need to call the django view that updates the database...

Comment: thanks @miki725: But my question is how do I write the url to reference the regular expression from my urls.py? Each `<div class='rate'>` item will have a different url that needs to be referenced... Is the regex same for python and javascript?

Comment: @NickB - Why would you need to use regular expression for the url in the AJAX call? Each `(div class='rate')` should already have its unique url, which is generated by `{% url thing_rating %}` and is assigned to the corresponding anchor. Raunak's solution is exactly what you need, as I understand your question.